# Flutter: how to delete item in ListTile

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout, navigator

If i use Navigator, class is finished by itself.
I just want to delete the list.

[code image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA7kl.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "class is finished by itself"

Comment: You don't have itemCount: items.length,

Comment: Thank you for asking. It means that the page(view) is finished.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Espc. don't paste screen-shots of code, ask a precise question, include things you already tried

Answer (score 2):

```js
  body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: launchButton('linkbutton','https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'),
              trailing: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                 
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `itemCount` to your `ListView.Builder`.

Then if you want to delete the item at the given index, you can create a function and put it in your `onpressed`

```
deleteItem(int index){
  yourList.removeWhere(index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i create a function and put it in onpressed?

Comment: to simplify it you can simply write yourList.removeWhere(index); in your onpressed method. Instead of writing 100 in itemcount create a list with data, name it e.g. yourList and then you call yourList.length